# Google Places Api Always throws Error + ios

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am just start to learn how to use google places api in ios. I followed all the step given https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/start. But I am always getting the error:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. The Places API could not find the user's location. This may be because the user has not allowed the application to access location information.

I just written the sample code

```
placesClient?.currentPlaceWithCallback({
(placeLikelihoodList:GMSPlaceLikelihoodList?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
if let error = error {
print("Pick Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
return
}
self.nameLbl.text = "No current place"
self.addressLbl.text = ""
if let placeLikelihoodList = placeLikelihoodList {
let place = placeLikelihoodList.likelihoods.first?.place
if let place = place {
self.nameLbl.text = place.name
self.addressLbl.text = place.formattedAddress!.componentsSeparatedByString(",").joinWithSeparator("\n")
}
}
})
```

I am not getting the where am wrong. I also try for Google Place Autocomplete, it throwing me a error. I had followed all step from pod installation to Api Key generation as per https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/start

Comment: Two things you could check. 1. Did you request permission to use location services from the user already? 2. If you're using the simulator, have you told the simulator where to make it look like your device is? Sometime by default it doesn't have a location set.

Comment: I am using simulator. I had set debug->location->custom location

Comment: Have you updated your apps plist file to include "requestWhenInUseAuthorization"?

Comment: Now it working with Simulator , but not working with device iphone 6 ios 8.1 i had turn on location. Under privacy ->Location Service it shows my apps.

Comment: any solution for this i am also getting this error every time